# AWS Sagemaker error INVALID_INFERENCE_TYPE

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I have a simple sagemaker endpoint hello world model. The container works fine locally but when deployed in Sagemaker endpoint givs error below..

```
{
    "ErrorCode": "INVALID_INFERENCE_TYPE",
    "Message": "Endpoint myEndpoint does not support this inference type."
}
```

Comment: Can you add more details, such as the algorithm, inference data?

Comment: I am using a fake model and inference.... following this documentation https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/scikit_bring_your_own.html

Comment: If I follow the example as-is, it runs without issues. Are you using a different data/model?

Comment: I am uploading the model in s3 from my local machine, uploading docker image in ECR and creating model, endpoint configuration, endpoint from AWS Console which gives this error. Do I need to call Estimator or something for it to work?

Comment: You won't need the estimator if you already have a trained model. Any chance it's set as an [async endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/async-inference.html)? On the UI when creating the endpoint, if you've entered in params in the Async Invocation Config section, it might be set up as an async endpoint. Otherwise, any chance you can share the code/model? Hard to debug otherwise.

Comment: @durga_sury Yes, it was in async which is why this error. Thank you! Can you post it as answer so I can give you the credits?

Comment: @durga_sury can you post your comment as answer so I can give you bounty (expires in 5 hours)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comment from @durga_sury above.... quoted below.

> You won't need the estimator if you already have a trained model. Any chance it's set as an async endpoint? On the UI when creating the endpoint, if you've entered in params in the Async Invocation Config section, it might be set up as an async endpoint. Otherwise, any chance you can share the code/model? Hard to debug otherwise. –
> durga_sury
> Sep 21 at 22:18

Seems just adding async options makes the endpoint async! After that you will get the error if you call it for real-time prediction.